# Rails Api + AngularJS + IonicFramework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, installation, ionic-framework

I want to start a new project and im not sure, if im using the best setup/approach. The project is kind of a list directory without high computing power needed.

I planned to build an website with Rails Api and AngularJs (+Bootstrap) for normal devices and mobile and use the same api for apps too.

Therefore i planned to use the IonicFramework (+PhoneGap). Is this a common approach or are there any best practices i should consider?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the standard way to develop web/desktop apps and mobile apps. 
You are approaching this correctly.

- Use core AngularJS + Bootstrap for web/desktop app and Ionic
  Framework for mobile
- Sharing the backend Rails API makes sense. Typically the Rails API
  would be designed with REST principles in mind which makes it easier
  to consume (probably using Restangular) via web/desktop app and
  mobile app
- If you follow standard AngularJS conventions to create a separation
  of concerns (controllers, services, and views) then you will be able
  to share quite a bit of JavaScript code between the web/desktop app
  and mobile app and easily override functionality to customize for
  devices, if necessary.